# Why we need Async task any way default web API request will be running by creating or reusing existing thread only

Tags: c#, async-await, task, webapi

Why we need Async task in WebApi c#, any way default web API request will be running by creating or reusing existing thread only. so threading is already used?

Comment: What if two people want to connect to your API at the same time?  Or 10?  Should they wait for the other people's requests to finish before theirs is serviced?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't make heads or tails of your question. Please consider rewriting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't confuse asynchronous with parallel.

Asynchronous means that the current thread is freed while you are waiting for a response to some I/O operation. (local storage, a network request, etc.)

Parallel means running two or more sets of code at the same time. This is multi-threading.

Asynchronous code isn't about multi-threading. Actually the opposite: Part of the benefit of asynchronous code is to *not* need more threads.

For example, consider a web API call that reads data from a database. What happens when 1000 requests come in at the same time?

If the code is written synchronously, you need a separate thread for each request. But ASP.NET has a maximum thread count. So that max will be reached, and the rest of the requests will have to wait until some of the first requests are completed before they can even *start*.

If the code is written asynchronously, then as soon as the database request is made, the thread is freed while it waits for a response from the database. During that waiting time, ASP.NET can use that thread to start processing a new request.

The result is that you need less threads to do the same amount of work. That also means that you can do *more* work with the same amount of resources.

Microsoft has a very well-written series of articles on this that are worth reading: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). That article has an analogy about making breakfast that helps explain what asynchronous programming is really about.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Gabriel you are right

Find the more clear answer
from the link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49850842/958539

Now let's open file in "asynchronous" mode:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomeFileReallyAsync(RequestParameters p) {
    string filePath = Preprocess(p);
    byte[] data;
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous)) {
        data = new byte[fs.Length];
        await fs.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    return PostProcess(data);
}
```

How many threads we need now? Now 1 thread is enough, in theory. When you open file in "asynchronous" mode - reads and writes will utilize (on windows) windows overlapped IO.

In simplified terms it works like this: there is a queue-like object (IO completion port) where OS can post notifications about completions of certain IO operations. .NET thread pool registers one such IO completion port. There is only one thread pool per .NET application, so there is one IO completion port.

When file is opened in "asynchronous" mode - it binds its file handle to this IO completion port. Now when you do ReadAsync, while actual read is performed - no dedicated (for this specific operation) thread is blocked waiting for that read to complete. When OS notify .NET completion port that IO for this file handle has completed - .NET thread pool executes continuation on thread pool thread.

Now let's see how processing of 100 requests with 1ms interval can go in our scenario:

Request 1 goes in, we grab thread from a pool to execute 1ms pre-processing step. Then thread performs asynchronous read. It doesn't need to block waiting for completion, so it returns to the pool.

Request 2 goes in. We have a thread in a pool already which just completed pre-processing of request 1. We don't need an additional thread - we can use that one again.

Same is true for all 100 requests.

After handling pre-processing of 100 requests, there are 200ms until first IO completion will arrive, in which our 1 thread can do even more useful work.

IO completion events start to arrive - but our post-processing step is also very short (1ms). Only one thread again can handle them all.

This is an idealized scenario of course, but it shows how not "async await" but specifically asynchronous IO can help you to "save threads".

What if our post-processing step is not short but we instead decided to do heavy CPU bound work in it? Well, that will cause thread pool starvation. Thread pool will create new threads without delay, until it reaches configurable "low watermark" (which you can obtain via ThreadPool.GetMinThreads() and change via ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()). After that amount of threads is reached - thread pool will try to wait for one of the busy threads to become free. It will not wait forever of course, usually it will wait for 0.5-1 seconds and if no thread become free - it will create a new one. Still, that delay might slow your web application quite a bit in heavy load scenarios. So don't violate thread pool assumptions - don't run long CPU-bound work on thread pool threads.